# jQuery addClass to element with same class name with Waypoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-waypoints

I have an event in which I need to add a class to an element with a matching class name.
For example:

```
<a class="one"></div>
<a class="two"></div>

<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

How do I find and add an additional class to the element with the matching class name?
Here is my script, I need it to target the  tag with matching class.

```
jQuery('div.two').waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'down') {
    jQuery(this).addClass("active") // to <a> element that shares same class
  }
  else {
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're asking...are you wondering how to select by class, and then add more classes to that?

Comment: What should the end result be?

Comment: put a little more effort ( and research ) into your questions please. WHere is your current code?

Comment: added some more details, sorry I was trying to make it simp but I think it backfired.

Comment: How are the relevant elements selected for the waypoints plugin? Will those elements only ever have one class-name, or are there multiple classes used? Will any/all classes in the `div` elements be present on the `a` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this plugin but I'll give it a shot. Based off what you've provided I think your problem is:

```
jQuery(this).addClass("active")
```

Since you already know the class, just do:

```
var tempClass = $(this).attr("class");
jQuery("a."+tempClass).addClass("active");
```

Comment: I'm trying to add a new class to element with a matching class name.

Comment: @Sam what do you mean by matching class name? Can you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish a little more please?

Comment: Yes. I updated the original post. For example when you scroll past <div class="one"> I need to add class "active" to <a class="one">

Comment: You are on the right track but the problem is the class names are added dynamically via a CMS so I can't hard code them into the script that way.

Comment: @Sam Updated again, but if these are dynamic, binding event listeners will be difficult, not sure that will be possible, unless you can give them all a universal class.

Comment: `class` is a restricted word in javascript

Answer (score 1):

Just select by class names.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".one"), function(el) {
    el.classList.add("whateverClass");
});
```

Instead of a for loop, this uses the prototype method `forEach` with the `call` method to turn the NodeList into an array list, adding the class to each element with the class "one"

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/PGVgTyBxdeiGgByzPm0i?p=preview)

Comment: If you're using `Array.prototype.forEach()` you might as well use [`Element.classList.add('whateverClass')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).

Comment: @charlietfl updated to add a check for the class exists

Comment: edit: classList.add wont duplicate classes, so that check was not needed

Comment: In all fairness, `Array.forEach` is supported in more browsers than `classlist.add`, mainly the latter is not supported in IE9

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to remove the class from the others first, then add to the applicable `<a>`

```
jQuery('div.two').waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'down') {
     /* remove prior active class */
     jQuery("a.active").removeClass('active');
     /* add to current one */
     jQuery("a.two").addClass('active');
  }
  else {
  }
});
```

To make this more generic I would add a class like `waypoint` to all the content elements as well as a `data-point` to be able to simplify instances.

```
<div data-point="one" class="waypoint"></div>
```

JS

```
jQuery('.waypoint').waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'down') {
     /* remove prior active class */
     jQuery("a.active").removeClass('active');
     /* add to current one */
      var linkClass=$(this).data('point')
     jQuery("a." + linkClass).addClass('active');
  }
  else {
  }
});
```

Comment: This is close, the issue is the class names "one two etc" are generated dynamically via a CMS.

Comment: @sam just added a more generic solution